# Whenever I am executing the program, it is taking an undesired extra input at the last

Tags: c, printf, stdin, scanf, fflush

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char name[3];
    float price[3];
    int pages[3];

    printf("Enter names, price and no of pages of 3 books:\n ");
    fflush(stdin);
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        scanf(" %c%f%d\n",&name[i],&price[i],&pages[i]);

    printf("And this is what you have entered:\n ");
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        printf(" %c %f  %d  \n",name[i],price[i],pages[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `\n` from `scanf`.

```
  scanf(" %c%f%d\n",&name[i],&price[i],&pages[i]);    
           //   ^^ Remove it.
```

With `\n` in `scanf`, on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `scanf` will skip the `\n` passed to input buffer and expecting a non `\n` character to stop reading from the input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

As per `C11` standard document, chapter 7.21.5.2, `fflush()` function, (emphasis mine)

> `int fflush(FILE *stream);`
>
> If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; ***otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.***

So, basically, `fflush(stdin)` invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, as mentioned by Mr **@Haccks**, you should get rid of the `\n` from the format string supplied in `scanf()`.

Comment: Although C standard prohibits use of `fflush(stdin)` , it is well defined by some [libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) and APIs.

Comment: @haccks Thank for sharing this info sir. However, to play safe (and portable), we shouldn't use `fflush(stdin)`. Please correct me if I am wrong. :-)

Comment: I would say it is better to stick with C standard.

Comment: Thanks Sourav Ghosh and haccks for rectifying the mistake.